# How to make static an html attribute in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a react chat app and here's my issue; I am trying to make an attribute named `msgSntInRm` of the `p` elements created actually keep track of which room the message was sent in upon creation. But with the below code the attribute changes based on the state of whichever room is selected, even after the message was sent/created.

```
<div className='chatDisplay'>
    {
        this.state.testArr.map((msg, pos, array) =>
                <p className='testArr'
                    testArrPos={pos} 
                    msgSntInRm={this.state.currentRoom}>
                    {msg}
                </p>
            )
        }
</div>
```

I understand why this is happening. Here is my constructor:

```
class RoomList extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
    rooms: [],
    display: 'none',
    displayRoom: 'none',
    newRoomName: 'New room',
    currentRoom: '',
    testArr: [],
    msgSntIn: ''
};

this.roomsRef = this.props.firebase.database().ref('rooms');
}
```

I'm just not sure on exactly how to fix this. [Here is a GIST of the code](https://gist.github.com/DravionV/40082a48f1085199fc40ffc855b370ee)

I need to replace the code `this.state.currentRoom` with something that tracks the room the message was created in and also it cant change ever again once I leave the room or create new messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should correlate a message to a room, using the current room in the state won't do much good.

instead of storing messages as an array of strings, store an array of objects, each message will be like:
`{ msg: 'bla bla', room: 'room1', // other properties }`

That way, when you iterate your messages, you could specify on which room the message was sent according to the message object data.

Comment: Yes this approach would make the most sense. I will turn the array into an array of objects. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `msgSntIn` should be placed directly in the `RoomList` component state, but inside an object element of `this.state.testArr`.

You could refactor your submitTweet function's setState like this:

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
  return {
    testArr: prevState.testArr.concat({
      content: content,
      msgSntIn: roomNo
    })
  }
});
```

Also note that you should use setState whenever you want to modify a component's state. If you need the previous state you can pass `setState` a callback and the first argument will be the previous state and the second argument the previous props.

Your Message component could look like this:

```
const Message = (props) => {
   return (<p msgSntIn={props.msgSntIn} key={props.key}>{props.content}</p>)
}
```

In your render function you could do something like this:

```
this.state.rooms.map((room, indexPos ) => {
  return (<Message msgSntIn={room.msgSntIn} content={room.content} key={props.key} />
})
```